# Limiting entries in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Alrighty! I'm working on small chat add-on for my website, and when a user logs on they'll see the chat history, I'm using a Javascript Object to store all messages in my NodeJS server, now I'd like it so whenever more than fifty entries are in the Object it adds the latest message and removes the oldest, I'd like this to limit my server from handling a lot of messages every time a user logs on. How would I be doing this?

Here's how I store my messages,

```
            var messages = {
                "session":[

                ]
            };

            messages.session.push(
                {
                    "name":user.name,
                    "message":safe_tags_replace(m.msg),
                    "image":user.avatar,
                    "user":user.steamid,
                    "rank":user.rank,
                }               
            );
```

I could also just do loading the last fifty messages in the JSON Object but whenever I run my server for a long time without restarting it this Object will become extremly big, would this be a problem?

Comment: check length of `messages.session` - if > 50, `shift` off older messages. - also, there is zero JSON in your question - that is a plain ol' javascript object (JSON is a string, always a string and nothing but a string)

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I'm quite new to Objects and Arrays and all that stuff, but I get how I would check for if the length exceeds 50 messages/entries, let me give it a shot. Thanks!

Edit: it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are pushing elements to the end of your array, you could just use array shift() to remove the first element of the array if needed. e.g.

```
var MAX_MESSAGES = 50;    
if (messages.session.length > MAX_MESSAGES) { messages.session.shift(); }
```

To answer the second part of your question:

The more data you hold, the more physical memory you consume on the client machine, obviously. Which can - by itself - be a problem, especially for mobile devices and on old hardware. Also; having huge arrays will impact performance on lookup, iteration, some insert operations and sorting.

Comment: Yup! That seems to be working perfectly! Also, if I'd where to get exact fifty messages I'd need to set MAX_MESSAGES to 49 since Javascript starts counting from zero, thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Storing JSON objects that contain chat history in the server is not a good idea. For one you are taking up memory that will be held up for an indefinite period. If you have multiple clients all taking to each other, these objects will continue to grow are eventually impact performance. Secondly once the server is restarted, or after your clenan up these objects, the chat history is lost. 
The ideal solution is to store message in a database; a simple solution is mongoDB. Whenever a user logs in to the app. Query the db for that users chat history (here you can define how far back you want to go) and send them an initial response contain this data. Then whenever a message is sent, insert that message into the table/collection for future reference. This way the server is only responsible for sending chat history during the initial signon. After that the client is responsible for maintaining any added new message.

Comment: I've always wondered, are database really the way to go for storing a few strings, I don't need to store a lot, it's a general chat that won't contain more than fifty messages. I do understand what you mean but I feel like it's not really needed in this case, is it?

Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: If you are certain you can control the number of users and actually dont want to store any message. Then ya this is a perfectly valid solution, 100,1000 even 10000 messages are a trivial amount and will pose no issues to maintain in memory, just be sure its not going to go out of control.

Comment: thank you! in this case I'll be always limiting the server to 50 messages for one general chat only! Thanks for the handy-dandy information tho!